# Epigenetic heritable pathways in ADHD

Tags: genetics, adhd

ADHD is largely believed to be a heritable neural disorder. However, as I understand the details of the heritable pathway (or pathways?) are largely unsettled.
Recently I stumbled over [this paper](https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/18492038/) suggesting slash hypothetizing a heritable pathway that goes via epigenetics. This would connect both, the environmental with the genetic theories to some extend, and also give an explanation for how to possibly therapize the disorder beyond the symptomatic treatment of stimulants. So all in all, this would be a very promising way forward.

Now, the above mentioned paper is from 2008 and I could not find any follow ups, so I wanted to ask whether anybody knows whats the current understanding regarding the role of epigenetics in the heritability of ADHD? More recent review articles warmly welcome!

Thanks!